# How can get id of an element by clicking on it and not invoking the click functionality bound on that tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating a editor mode when invoked on any page it will disable all the click functionalities(angular buttons, links, tabs, anything else) on the page and when I click on the element it should return the id/class of that tag and once I exit the editor mode everything works the same way.

"pointer-events": "none" //doesnt let me click for getting the id of element (using jquery to get the element id)

```
this.TagPointerJquery = $(document).click((test: any) => {
console.log(this);
console.log(test);
for (var element of test.originalEvent.path) {
  if (element.attributes.hasOwnProperty("tutorial")) {
    $("#" + element.attributes.id.nodeValue).css({
      "border": "1px solid black"
    });
  }
}
```

});

Comment: have you tried on hover instead of onclick?

Comment: Have you tried unbinding then rebinding? See $().off and $().on in jQuery documentation.

Comment: I have to select the element and open dialog and provide inputs so it needs to be clicked.

Comment: @Cybernetic I tried $(document).off('click'), but didnt work, it just off the .on.

Comment: its just like create same functionality like inspect element in browser but on my web page.

Comment: Just keep the click event. Don’t disable it, but put a condition inside the click event to check which mode you’re in. So if you’re in edit mode then it does one thing and if you’re not in edit mode it does another. You can use preventDefault() to prevent the normal click event as needed.

Comment: @Cybernetic Yes, I did the same thing. Instead of using `$(document).click((test: any)` I used `document.addEventListener("click", this.callback, true);`
this helped me to use capturing the then preventDefault() in callback function. 
Thanks for the help.